# partition mysql table on a none primary key column

Tags: mysql, database, partitioning, bigsql

I have a table:

```
+----+---------+----------+
| id | user_id | comment  |
+----+---------+----------+
```

Where column type is:

- id (bigint not null primary key autoincrement)
- user_id (bigint not null)
- comment (text)

How can I partition this table on `user_id` by range? I tried to partition this table by range in PHPMyAdmin but doesn't allow me because `user_id` isn't a primary key. If I have many 10 billion users and each has an infinite amount of comments this table will be very large. I want to partition it like:

```
partition 1 (user_id<500)
+----+---------+----------+
| id | user_id | comment  |
+----+---------+----------+
partition 2 (user_id<1000)
+----+---------+----------+
| id | user_id | comment  |
+----+---------+----------+
```

And so on.

Comment: There is no benefit from partitioning the table.  Use the indexes, but not the partitioning, that danblack suggests.

Comment: thanks, Rick james.but as I mentioned I have for example 10billion users, and each user can have multiple comments.let's say every user posts 1 million comments.that means in this table I have 1 million rows for one user.and every partition will be 1000000*500.500

Comment: Let's see the important `SELECTs`; I'll explain why non-partitioning is just as good as partitioning, perhaps even better.  I'll start with:  If all `SELECTs` include `where user_id = constant`, then having `user_id` first in the relevant index is very good; even better is to have `PRIMARY KEY(user_id, ...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, since `user_id` is not part of the table `primary key(s)` or `unique keys` you can't create partitions solely for the `user_id` on your table as the [DOCs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-limitations-partitioning-keys-unique-keys.html) states very clearly

> ***every unique key on the table must use every column in the table's partitioning expression***

So for your case what you **can** do is to add a `unique key` on your table for both `id` and `user_id`

```
alter table myTable add unique key uk_id_userid (id, user_id);
```

And then add the range partition for only `user_id` column as such:

```
alter table myTable partition by range (user_id) (
    PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (10),
    PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (20),
    PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (30),
    PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (40)
);
```

**Note** Since you already have a table with values in order to define your partition ranges you need to wrap around all existing values for your `user_id` column in your partitions. That is if you have a `user_id` of `1000` you can not define your last partition as `PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (1000)` that will fail. You will need one more partition i.e.: `PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (2000)` or `PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE`

See it working here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8ca7ed

Full working example:

```
create table myTable (
   id bigint not null auto_increment,
   user_id bigint not null,
   comment text,
   key (id)
) engine=InnoDb;

insert into myTable (user_id, comment) values 
   (1, 'bla'), (1, 'ble'), (1, 'bli'), (1, 'blo'), 
   (12, 'bla'), (12, 'ble'), (12, 'bli'), (12, 'blo'), 
   (23, 'bla'), (23, 'ble'), (23, 'bli'), (23, 'blo'), 
   (34, 'bla'), (34, 'ble'), (34, 'bli'), (34, 'blo');

alter table myTable add unique key uk_id_userid (id, user_id);

alter table myTable partition by range (user_id) (
    PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (10),
    PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (20),
    PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (30),
    PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (40)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you have satisfied the criteria of when to use partitioning. This is a rather rare case and needs to map closely to your queries. A 500 user range seems tiny. MySQL can handle large tables without partitioning so don't assume its necessary.

The form is:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
id bigint unsigned AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
user_id bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
COMMENT TEXT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (user_id, id),
key(id))
PARTITION BY RANGE (user_id) (
  PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (500),
  PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (1000),
  PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (2000),
  PARTITION p3  VALUES LESS THAN (3000)
);
```

ref: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=b8a7289a45163519be18bb4ef1b85463)

Comment: You must make the auto_increment column first in the PK in InnoDB.

Comment: I [tried](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=ff0f21f0b1de766b1de9683bd2e0fe4e) on all version from MySQL-5.5+ and all available mariadb versions. In all cases the AI seemed to be incrementing. Why must it be first?

Comment: Ah, I see. It works because `id` is the first column of another index.

Comment: yep. and for completeness `key(id)` couldn't be declared unique because of the partitioning.

Comment: The only requirement for an auto_inc column is that it be the _first_ column in _some_ index.  Neither `UNIQUEness`, not `PRIMARYness` is required.

Comment: @danblack - The partitioning buys no performance benefit.  The trick with `PRIMARY KEY(user_id, id)` does.  But that can be used exactly as written with a non-partitioned table.

Comment: thanks.but as I mentioned I have for example 10billion users, and each user can have multiple comments.let's say every user posts 1 million comments.that means in this table I have 1 million row for one user.and every partition will be 1000000*500.500 users and each user 1 million comments.if I do not partition table it will be very large as time past.may be after one month I have 10 billion rows in that table.are indexes are god for any large table like more than 10 billion and infinity table that grows as time passes.

Comment: fantasy numbers aside, big doesn't mean needing partitions. Partitions are good for dropping and swapping. But sure, index it correctly.

Comment: [examine the nodejs result object](https://www.tutorialkart.com/nodejs/nodejs-mysql-result-object/), it dffers depending on the sql statement type.